# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@WebApp/domain' in '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/web/src'

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm creating pipeline for a web application in a monorepo project which also as mobile app code, while creating the build for the web , it cannot access the domain folder which is outside the web folder, so I'm getting module not found error in the run build command, how to access the domain folder

This is the folder structure

Consumer-frontend

-domain
-mobile
-web
-package-lock.json
-bitbucket-pipelines.yml

This is the pipeline code

```
pipelines:
  branches: 
    test-deploy-2:
      - step:
          name: Building the app
          image: node:18.14.2
          script:
            - cd web
            - npm install
            - npm run build
          artifacts:
           - build/**
      - step:
          name: Deploying the app to S3
          deployment: test
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.2.4
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                ACL: "public-read"
                LOCAL_PATH: "./web/build"
```

This is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "WebApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mantine/carousel": "^5.8.0",
    "@mantine/hooks": "^5.9.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.113",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.13",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.9",
    "@WebApp/domain": "file:../domain",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/react-otp-input": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
    "array-move": "^4.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "embla-carousel-autoplay": "^7.0.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^8.1.7",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.4",
    "html-to-text": "^9.0.3",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-audio-voice-recorder": "^1.0.4",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-drag-reorder": "^1.2.0",
    "react-media-recorder": "^1.6.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-sketch-canvas": "^6.2.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-sortablejs": "^6.1.4",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
    "suneditor": "^2.44.3",
    "suneditor-react": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-core": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-expiration": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-precaching": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-routing": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-strategies": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-streams": "^6.5.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "^7.21.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "@types/sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
    "polyfill": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Im trying to build the project and save the artifacts in the build folder, but build step is failing with error** Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@WebApp/domain' in '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/web/src'**

Comment: Since the error says it's looking in /web/src, your path might need go up two levels

Comment: Please format the "folder structure", possibly with bullet items or a code block. It is hard to understand it as your wrote it. Also format the error message as a code block please.